# Get the name of the last mutation that occured in VueX

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm using namespaced VueX modules and within each module state there are handlers to determine if my API call has completed or not, firing a mutation with the name of 'MODULENAME_LOADING'. When the API call is completed, it fires other mutations to set the data to the state. 
I want to be able to search, from a parent layout component, if the last mutation commit contains the word 'LOADING' in it, but can't find a way to get the last mutation name.

Is there a way to check from within a component what was the last mutation or do I have to handle each module separately?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vuex offers a [subscribe](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribe) method to allow the View to listen to Store mutations (and subscribeAction for actions). It looks like this:

```js
...
data() {
  return { 
    unsubFn: null,
    lastMutation: null
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.unsubFn = this.$store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
    this.lastMutation = mutation.type;
  });
},
beforeDestroy() {
  if(this.unsubFn) {
    this.unsubFn();
  }
}
...
```

Here is a basic example of it in action: https://codepen.io/Qumez/pen/oNNyexB

Calling subscribe returns a function to allow you to unsubscribe, which you absolutely want to do in order to prevent duplicate actions firing when a mutation occurs. I prefer to store it in the data() function and call it in the beforeDestroy() hook.

Comment: Glad to help. Happy coding!